# Futures executed in order although there is no dependency

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
  def f1: Future[Unit] = Future {
    Thread sleep 10000
    println("1")
    1
  }

  def f2: Future[Unit] = Future {
    Thread sleep 5
    println("2")
  }

  def f3(x: Unit, y: Unit): Future[Unit] = Future {
    Thread sleep 10
    println("3")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val f = for {
      r1 <- f1
      r2 <- f2
      r3 <- f3(r1, r2)
    } yield r3

    Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
  }
```

`f3` depends on `f2` and `f1`

there is no dependency between `f1` and `f2`

If I run the code I get:

```
1
2
3
```

I would like `f1` and `f2` to be ran in parallel but before `f3`.
So because `f2` should terminate before `f1` the output should be:

```
2
1
3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot run them in parallel and expect one to finish before the other.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/3zofjl/why_is_future_totally_unusable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val f = f1 zip f2 flatMap f3.tupled
```

Or, if you insist on using `for` comprehension for some reason:

```
val f = for {
   (r1, r2) <- f1 zip f2
   r3 <- f3(r1, r2)
} yield r3
```

Comment: Thanks! I just have one secondary question: If zip has type `[a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`, then when you use it on two `Future[Unit]` the result should be `Future[(Unit, Unit)]`. Shouldn't that mean the results of the two initial futures are returned at the same time? If the explanation is too long, could you please redirect me to some article on this?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "are returned". The resulting future is satisfied when both original futures are satisfied, yes, that's the whole point. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Your for-comprehension forces them to execute in that order. The for-comprehension is actually syntactic sugar for the `map`, `flatMap` and `withFilter` functions. In your case, just `flatMap`. It will be expanded to this expression:

```
f1.flatMap(r1 => f2.flatMap(r2 => f3(r1, r2)))
```

As you can see here, the function passed to `f1.flatMap` won't be called until f1 is finished executing.

A simple way to solve this problem, would be to instantiate the futures before the for-comprehension, like this:

```
val future1 = f1
val future2 = f2

val f = for {
    r1 <- future1
    r2 <- future2
    r3 <- f3(r1, r2)
} yield r3
```

Comment: Why is it different for vals?

Comment: A val will be evaluated immediately. A def will be evaluated each time you use it. A lazy val will be evaluated the first time you use it.

Comment: I know that, but I thought that putting a future as a value of some val will simply (immediately) evaluate the value to be a future of some operation, not to also start the operation itself right away. Does this mean that in the code you posted, whole for comprehension happens with ten-or-so second delay (not until all futures are calculated)?

Comment: I mean, as you said it yourself, only difference between val and def should be in the fact that def is evaluated when needed and val right away. But how can this cause Future vals to be performed simultaneously, while defs are synchronized? And doesn't this completely screw up referential transparency since it seems that I cannot simply substitute future1 and future2 with f1 and f2?